# Where are Apache Giraph logs (with log4j) located?

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, giraph

I am currently experimenting with Apache Giraph using the configuration described in the [QuickStart Tutorial](https://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html) :

- Ubuntu 12
- Hadoop 0.20
- Giraph Release 1.2

I am running all computation on a single-node local cluster, as described in the QuickStart.

While running the example computations and other custom codes work fine, I am unable to retrieve/locate the logs expected whith log4j logger.

**Could you indicate me where these logs are located, either in local system or HDFS ?**

Command used to launch Giraph computation :

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop path/to/giraph/jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner community.RevertedGraphComputation community.JsonLongLongDoubleVertexInputFormat /user/hduser/input/test_graph.txt community.VertexWithLongValueDoubleEdgeTextOutput /user/hduser/output/reverted
```

Thank you !

Abreviated version of the java code for logging :

```
//In RevertedGraphComputation class
 private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(RevertedGraphComputation.class);

 //In compute() method
 LOG.info("Vertex "+vertex.getId());
```

Comment: log4j.properties file should tell you where to find them

Comment: Thank you , could you indicate where this file is usually located ? Is it in hadoop directory? Or included within a jar?

Comment: Hadoop directory, but I've never used such an old version of Hadoop